# Unexpected packet from server localhost:9000, ::1

Tags: clickhouse

I have installed clickhouse as per the instructions here https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-rpm-install.

I have also enabled :: in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml.

It started fine as below:

sudo /etc/init.d/clickhouse-server restart
Start clickhouse-server service: Path to data directory in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml: /var/lib/clickhouse/
DONE

But, when i start client it fails as below:

sudo clickhouse-client
ClickHouse client version 1.1.54383.
Connecting to localhost:9000.
Code: 102. DB::NetException: Unexpected packet from server localhost:9000, ::1 (expected Hello or Exception, got Unknown packet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change port in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml and pass it as a parameter when launching client as below:

> clickhouse-client --port 9011

Answer (score 2):

Having the following error:

```
Code: 102. DB::NetException: Unexpected packet from server localhost:9000, ::1 (expected Hello or Exception, got Unknown packet)
```

means that **clickhouse-client** got an answer, but an incorrect one, which means that another software (not ClickHouse) is listening on **localhost:9000**
Highly likely it is **php-fpm**, because it also has port 9000 as a default one.

You can check what software is listening on port 9000 with the following command:

```
sudo netstat -antp|grep LIST|grep 9000
```

As a solution too the issue, you can do something like:

- change port to listen to for clickhouse
- change port to listen to for the software, which is currently
  listening on port 9000
- shutdown software, which is currently listening on port 9000

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when mixing https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#streaming-results with other queries.

It has nothing to do with other services listening on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add user name `default` when connecting to clickhouse.