# fail to connect to remote clickhouse-server with clickhouse-client

Tags: clickhouse

I hosted a clickhouse server on azure VM **(I'm able to run clickhouse-client inside the VM)** with a nginx proxy, below is the nginx setting

```
      server {
           listen  5000;
           server_name     myhost.cloudapp.azure.com;
           location / {
                   proxy_pass http://localhost:8123;
           }


   server {
           listen  6000;
           server_name     myhost.cloudapp.azure.com;
           location / {
                   proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
           }
```

I'm able to curl both endpoint with proper response, e.g.

```
curl http://myhost.cloudapp.azure.com:6000                
Port 9000 is for clickhouse-client program.
You must use port 8123 for HTTP.

curl http://myhost.cloudapp.azure.com:5000                
Ok.
```

However, when i try to do `clickhouse-client -h myhost.cloudapp.azure.com --port 6000`, I get the following.

```
 clickhouse-client -h myhost.cloudapp.azure.com --port 6000
 ClickHouse client version 21.1.2.15 (official build).
 Connecting to myhost.cloudapp.azure.com:6000 as user default.
 Code: 102. DB::NetException: Unexpected packet from server bs- 
 clickhouse.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:6000 (expected Hello or Exception, got Unknown packet)
```

The connection setting for clickhouse-server is as following:

```
<listen_host>::</listen_host>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any hints are appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that port 6000 is not shared with another app (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490543/unexpected-packet-from-server-localhost9000-1)?

Comment: Check that version of *clickhouse-server* and *clickhouse-client* the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9000 -- tcp protocol not HTTP. You need to configure nginx as TCP reverse proxy

[NGINX transparent TCP proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140741/nginx-transparent-tcp-proxy)

```
stream {
  upstream syslog {
    server sapvmlogstash01.sa.projectplace.com:514;
    server sapvmlogstash02.sa.projectplace.com:514;
  }
  server {
    listen 514;
    proxy_pass syslog;
  }
}
```